# Check multiple Classes for style="color: ...."

Tags: javascript

as example i have an Class called 'foo' with a length of 100.

Now i want to find out which one of those 100 have an style (color).
Only one of them has a color, but the order is random so i can't get the class by `foo[100]` because its random between 1-100

One of them looks like: `<span style="color:yellow;">hello</span>` 
So how can i get this one? I have checked already many other questions here, but i couldn't find anything about this part.

It looks like:

```
<div class="foo"> <div><span style="color:yellow;">2</span></div></div>
<div class="foo"> <div><span>1</span></div></div>
<div class="foo"> <div><span>2</span></div></div>
<div class="foo"> <div><span>1</span></div></div>
```

Comment: DOM Elements sorry...  :/

Comment: It ends right after it ...
<div class="foo"> <div><span>1</span></div></div>

i've got it with document.querySelectorAll("div.foo") but now how to check them for the style='color:...'...

Comment: I want to find the div.foo at the end i just want to find the class number which includes the style='color:...'  part ... foo[0]  as example ... sorry for not posting all details right from the start ... i'll try to add as many infos as possible the next time. thanks for taking the time to check my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all the `div.foo` elements by using `querySelectorAll`. Then you can loop through those to find the first one containing a `span` with a color style by using `Array.prototype.find` to treat that collection like an array, and within the `find` callback, use `querySelectorAll` to find `span`s with a `style` attribute and then `Array.prototype.some` to find out whether one of those has a `color` style (as opposed to something else):

```js
// Find all `div.foo` elements
var fooList = document.querySelectorAll("div.foo");

// Find the first one that contains a `span` with a color style
var found = Array.prototype.find.call(fooList, function(div) {
  // `some` stops the first time its callback returns a truthy value
  return Array.prototype.some.call(div.querySelectorAll("span[style]"), function(span) {
    return !!span.style.color;
  });
});

// Show it
console.log(found.outerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="foo"><div><span style="color:yellow;">this one</span></div></div>
<div class="foo"><div><span>1</span></div></div>
<div class="foo"><div><span>2</span></div></div>
<div class="foo"> <div><span>1</span></div></div>
```

Note that in the `some` callback, we're using the fact that an element's `style` object's `color` property will be `""` (a falsy value) when there's no inline style for `color` on that element.

Note that we **can't** use an attribute substring match, `span[style*=color]`, because that would match elements we didn't want (for instance, `<span style="border-color: green">`).